# Not-clipped childview of RelativeLayout is not clickable

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have the following activity. It is an simplification of a draggable map. The problem is that mytext2 is not clickable, even if it is visible. Can anybody tell me how to make it clickable? And for some reason the inner-RelativeLayout gets not bigger than screen size, even when i set this high dp.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100000dp"
        android:layout_height="100000dp"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:translationX="-100dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:translationX="400dp"
            android:translationY="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:translationX="200dp"
            android:translationY="100dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

class

```
package com.example.relativatest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.mytext1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("HELLO!1");
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.mytext2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("HELLO!2");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100000dp"
        android:layout_height="100000dp"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:translationX="-100dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:translationX="400dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:translationY="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:translationX="200dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:translationY="100dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```